# is there a function to get mean values of a column for every unique date in date column?

Tags: time-series

[jupyter notebook screenshot showing al columns in the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC683.png)I have an AQI(Air Quality Index) dataset for which there are various columns such as O3, SO2, PM2.5,etc and a datetime column which has timestamps in it like (20-Sep-2017 - 01:00, 20-Sep-2017 - 00:00). I want to get mean value of columns for every unique date such as O3 has several values but I want only mean for 20-Sep-2017. I've tried regex, and many other things but did not get desired output.

Comment: What's the format of the dataset? Is it in file or in a variable? What language/framework are you using?

Comment: in excel, try averageif() or sumif(0 with countif()

Comment: thank you @SolarMike for your suggestion will try it as well..

Comment: @Aziz  . .. I am using a csv file in python language with help of pandas .. it is a tabular dataset...

Comment: @mayuresh I assume the `datetime` column includes both the date and time. You need to create a new column for the date only, then use [`df.groupby('date').mean()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) to get the mean values of the other columns per date. Please provide a sample dataset so that I can give you more details.

Comment: @Aziz thank you for your suggestion... will try it... also will post the sample dataset